# "falls sie selbst Arbeit bekommen sollten"

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verb

This post is on *sollte* as found in this excerpt from from chapter '[Weg nach Ramses](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/amerika-9768/13)' of *Amerika* (*Der Verschollene*) by Frankz Kafka.

> Sie [Delamarche und Robinson] hatten die Absicht, in das zwei Tagereisen von New York entfernte Städtchen Butterford zu marschieren, wo angeblich Arbeitsstellen frei waren. Sie hatten nichts dagegen, daß Karl mitkomme, und versprachen ihm erstens, zeitweilig seinen Koffer zu tragen, und zweitens, falls sie selbst Arbeit bekommen **sollten**, ihm eine Lehrlingsstelle zu verschaffen, was, wenn nur überhaupt Arbeit vorhanden sei, eine Leichtigkeit wäre.

**QUESTION**

1. If the narration were in the present tense, would it go like this (in relevant parts):

   > Sie versprechen, falls sie selbst Arbeit bekommen **sollen**, ihm eine Lehrlingsstelle zu verschaffen.
2. If Delemarche and Robinson were speaking to Karl, would it go:

   > Wir versprechen, falls wir selbst Arbeit bekommen **sollen**, Ihnen (dir) eine Lehrlingsstelle zu verschaffen.
3. (For question 3, I will assume that the answers to 1 and 2 are both yes.)  What is the meaning of *sollen* in the three sentences (including the original)?  If possible please also provide some sentences using the word in the same sense.
4. Would this be actually wrong, bad or not as good as the version with *sollen* in it or have a different meaning:

   > Wir versprechen, falls wir selbst Arbeit bekommen, Ihnen (dir) eine Lehrlingsstelle zu verschaffen.
5. If the answer to 1 or 2 is no, then that would mean *sollen* was not part of the original speech to Karl, but somehow got into the narration as part of narration or shifting of tenses.  In this case, please explain at what stage *sollen* goes into the narration and what is its meaning.

**BACKGROUND**

For question 3, my difficult is this.  I understand that *sollen* has a range of meanings from obligation to expectation.  See items 1 through 7 in the "sollen" section of this Dartmouth University [post](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Edeutsch/Grammatik/Verbs/modals.html). But the quoted promise seems to connect two (straightforward) events:  The two men's finding a job for themselves and finding an apprenticeship for Karl.  In other words, they seem to be saying, "When we find a job we'll get a place for you too."  Not, "When we are expected or obligated to. . . ."  Nor does item 8 of the Dartmouth list, "further development," seems to fit our case.

Comment: Have a hint: The subclause "...falls sie selbst Arbeit bekommen sollten." is in *present tense subjunctive*. Thus, a lot of your assumptions simply don't apply. You might want to re-write the question based on this hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sie versprachen ihm, falls sie selbst Arbeit bekommen **sollten**, ihm eine Lehrlingsstelle zu verschaffen.

This is tricky, because it's both indirect speech and a conditional. The conditional alone commands *Konjunktiv II* though. Indirect speech would have called for *Konjunktiv I*, but because the forms of first person plural are identical to *Indikativ*, the *Konjunktiv II* forms had to be used instead.

> Wir versprechen, falls wir selbst Arbeit bekommen soll**t**en, Ihnen (dir) eine Lehrlingsstelle zu verschaffen.

This isn't indirect speech anymore. BUT it's still a conditional. This is why the *Konjunktiv II* form *sollten* is still needed.

The meaning of **sollten** in both examples is **should this happen**.

> Ich rufe an, falls ich Hilfe brauchen sollte.
>
> Ich rufe an, sollte ich Hilfe brauchen.

*I will call, should I need help.*

---

Consider the *Indikativ* instead. *Sollen* (and English *shall*, too) has a different meaning in that mood:

> Ich rufe an, falls ich Hilfe brauchen soll.

*I will call, shall I need help.*

"I will call, if a third person requires me to accept her help."

---

> Wir versprechen, falls wir selbst Arbeit bekommen, Ihnen (dir) eine Lehrlingsstelle zu verschaffen.

This is fine in *Indikativ*, because *bekommen* does not have the side effects of *sollen* and the *falls* is enough to mark the conditional. If you go without *falls* you again need *Konjunktiv II*:

> Wir versprechen, sollten wir selbst Arbeit bekommen, Ihnen (dir) eine Lehrlingsstelle zu verschaffen.
>
> Wir versprechen, bekämen wir selbst Arbeit, Ihnen (dir) eine Lehrlingsstelle zu verschaffen.

---

Concluding, **sollte** is a helper for *Konjunktiv II* as **würde** is for *Konjunktiv I*. This is pretty similar to *should* and *would* in English.

Comment: Thank you. A question on the last bit. It seems *sollte* is a "helper" for KII in the sense that *sollten bekommen* can do the job of (replace) *bekämen*. But in the same sense wouldn't we want to say that *würde* helps KII (not KI)? For example: *Wenn ich schneller führe, **hätte** ich bestimmt einen Unfall.* *Wenn ich schneller führe, **würde** ich bestimmt einen Unfall **haben**.* (This example, from the Dartmouth page I linked in the main post.)

Comment: **Würde** is mainly the helper for indirect speech, because many *Konjunktiv I* forms are indistinguishable from the *Indikativ* forms. It's also used for *Konjunktiv II*, along with more helpers. In the above sentence, that helper is *bestimmt*, which turns *würde* into an irrealis helper. If you left it out, the clause could be understood as indirect speech. There are German dialects which prefer *sollte* instead of *würde bestimmt*. (Other words instead of *bestimmt*: *sicher, vielleicht, unter Umständen*, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

**Question 3 and 4:**
The word *"sollen"* can be used in a conditional sentence to *"amplify"* the condition (see [here](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Modalverb_sollen/Modalverb-sollen-Konditionalsatz)), in the sense that in

> Wenn sie Arbeit bekommen, verschaffen sie ihm eine Lehrstelle.

it is more likely that they find a job than in

> Wenn sie Arbeit bekommen sollten, verschaffen sie ihm eine Lehrstelle.

Equivalently,

> Falls sie Arbeit bekommen, verschaffen sie ihm eine Lehrstelle.

is more likely than

> Falls sie Arbeit bekommen sollten, verschaffen sie ihm eine Lehrstelle.

while they are both less likely than the first two examples.

When used in this sense, *"sollen"* is always written in *Konjunktiv II Präteritum*.

**Question 2 and 5:**
In direct speech the sentence would be

> Wir versprechen, falls wir selbst Arbeit bekommen sollten, dir eine Lehrstelle zu verschaffen.

**Question 1:**

> Sie versprechen, falls sie selbst Arbeit bekommen **sollten**, ihm eine Lehrlingsstelle zu verschaffen.

In case anything stayed unclear, please let me know.

Comment: You completely missed (like the OP) that this is indirect speech.

Comment: Neither of us missed it, as indicated in OP's question 2 and my answer to it...