# "sollte" and "wollte" in this passage from "Der Verschollene" by Kafka

Tags: subjunctive

This post is on *sollte* and *wollte* as found in this sentence from Der Verschollene by Franz Kafka (the "Asyl" chapter).

> Er **wollte** ja gern, wenn es sein mußte, Geschäftsdiener werden, aber schließlich war es ja gar nicht ausgeschlossen, daß er auch für reine Büroarbeit aufgenommen werden konnte und einstmals als Bürobeamter an seinem Schreibtisch sitzen und ohne Sorgen ein Weilchen lang aus dem offenen Fenster schauen würde wie jener Beamte, den er heute früh beim Durchmarsch durch die Höfe gesehen hatte. Beruhigend fiel ihm ein, als er die Augen schloß, daß er doch jung war und daß Delamarche ihn doch einmal freigeben würde; dieser Haushalt sah ja wirklich nicht danach aus, als sei er für die Ewigkeit gemacht. Wenn aber Karl einmal einen solchen Posten in einem Büro hätte, dann **wollte** er sich mit nichts anderem beschäftigen als mit seinen Büroarbeiten und nicht die Kräfte zersplittern wie der Student. Wenn es nötig sein **sollte**, **wollte** er auch die Nacht fürs Büro verwenden, was man ja im Beginn bei seiner geringen kaufmännischen Vorbildung sowieso von ihm verlangen würde. Er **wollte** nur an das Interesse des Geschäftes denken, dem er zu dienen hätte, und allen Arbeiten sich unterziehen, selbst solchen, die andere Bürobeamte als ihrer nicht würdig zurückweisen würden. Die guten Vorsätze drängten sich in seinem Kopf, als stehe sein künftiger Chef vor dem Kanapee und lese sie von seinem Gesicht ab.

**QUESTION**

I assume that *sollte* as occurring above is "amplifying the conditional" in the sense as explained in [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/43709/7629) to [another post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43708/falls-sie-selbst-arbeit-bekommen-sollten) and does not imply expectation or obligation as *sollen* usually does.

1. Do all or some occurrences of *wollte* above similarly "amplify the conditional" without any implication of desire or intention?

I believe the following questions might shed further light.  For this sentence:

> Er **wollte** nur an das Interesse des Geschäftes denken, dem er zu dienen hätte, und allen Arbeiten sich unterziehen, selbst solchen, die andere Bürobeamte als ihrer nicht würdig zurückweisen **würden**.

2. Can *wollte* be replaced with *würde* without changing the meaning of the sentence?
3. Can *würden* be replaced with *wollten* without changing the meaning of the sentence?

**BACKGROUND**

I have long been trying crack the mystery of *wollen*.  In several other posts, on *wollen* as occurring in other contexts, I got answers (to the effect) that *wollen* ALWAYS means a desire or intention:

- [Does "wollen" ever function like English "will" to signal a future event (no volition)](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24502/does-wollen-ever-function-like-english-will-to-signal-a-future-event-no-vol)
- [Can you use "wollen" in Konjunktiv II simply to mean what will happen (no volition)?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24520/can-you-use-wollen-in-konjunktiv-ii-simply-to-mean-what-will-happen-no-voliti)
- ["Karl, der seinen Koffer gerade hatte ordnen wollen"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43760/karl-der-seinen-koffer-gerade-hatte-ordnen-wollen)

I believe the case for reading *wollte* as not implying any desire or intention might be stronger in the passage cited above.  For example, *gern sein* already means desire and would not need another marker of desire.  Also, in

> Wenn es nötig sein **sollte**, **wollte** er auch...

*wollte* is matched with *sollte*, which according to the answer I quoted, can serve to amplify the conditional; and so might *wollte*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caution. *Sein sollen* has some tricky meanings. Same with the other auxiliary and modal combinations.

> Wenn es nötig sein sollte.

is simply another way of saying

> Wenn es nötig wäre.

---

1. All the occurences of *wollte* in Kafka's text can be replaced by *würde*. You lose the intentional aspect that way, however. That had to be guessed then. For the first *wollte* it's obvious because of *ja gern*, for the others not so. It would read as if Karl had a lucid dream instead.
2. Same as 1.
3. Not without a drastic change in meaning. If you write *wollten* you imply their intention is not successful. (And it's much more common to write *wollen würden* in that case, because *wollten* could also mean it's past tense.)

Comment: Thank you. (a) For "I would be tired all day if I were a shop clerk," would we say "ich würde" and never "ich wollte" because there is no intention involved (i.e. nobody wants to be tired)? (b) Unsuccessful meaning that the other employees would fail to refuse the chore and would have to do it? (c) Is this "unsuccessful" the same thing as Karl's not being a Geschäftsdiener though he "wollte" be one? In a word, counterfactuality?

Comment: a) *Als Verkäufer **wäre** mir den ganzen Tag langweilig.* or *Als Verkäufer würde ich mich den ganzen Tag langweilen.* — If you used *wollte* instead, you wish for being tired. b) Yes. c) No. The unsuccessful part is because of the context: *zurückweisen wollen* implies you don't want to do it, but you cannot avoid it. If they were successful, you would use *zurückgewiesen hätten.*