# Konjunktiv 2 von "wollen"

Tags: subjunctive, modal-verb

Die Fragebeschreibung habe ich vollständig umgearbeitet, damit unpräzise und überflüssige Formulierungen weggelassen werden.

In der ursprünglichen Frage bat ich um Informationen in Bezug auf den konjunktivischen Gebrauch vom Modalverb “wollen” in alten/modernen Texten sowie die diachronische Entwicklung von ihrem Präteritumstamm. Meine Frage lässt sich  mithilfe der folgenden Seiten und des unten angeführten Austauschs beantworten:

[Does "wollen" ever function like English "will" to signal a future event (no volition)](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24502/does-wollen-ever-function-like-english-will-to-signal-a-future-event-no-vol)

["sollte" and "wollte" in this passage from "Der Verschollene" by Kafka](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48052/sollte-and-wollte-in-this-passage-from-der-verschollene-by-kafka?noredirect=1&lq=1)

https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-wenn-man-koennte-wie-man-woellte-a-522262.html

https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Ubersicht_der_modalen_Bedeutungen

https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/1552

Comment: I’m not sure what kind of answer you are looking for. I find many instances of “als wollte er”.

Comment: You are right. But that is because "als" in this particular structure requires a verb in either Konjuktiv 1 or 2. I'd like to see some examples of "wollten" used independently.

Comment: https://www.visualstatements.net/visuals/visualstatements/wenn-er-wollte-wuerde-er-ein-satz-nach-dem-alle-frauen-leben-sollten/ :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no question is asked at all.

Comment: Hier steht keine Frage. Hier steht nur "Es gab eine ursprüngliche Frage" und "Es gibt 5 Websites in denen die Antwort steht", aber hier steht nichts was nach einer Antwort verlangt.

Comment: Die korrekte Lösung ist dann, seine eigene Frage zu beantworten: https://german.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Ich muss zugestehen, dass meine Frage nicht wohldurchdacht war. Trotzdem dürfte dieser Post nützlich sein, indem ein verhältnismäßig seltenes Thema darin behandelt wird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"wollen" in "er will dich gestern gesehen haben." ist der epistemische Gebrauch des Modalverbs.
Bei dieser Gebrauchsweise wird das Modalverb nicht im Infinitiv ans Ende des Satzes gestellt.

> würde gern erfahren, ob man solche Sätze mit Konjunktiv 2 umschreiben kann.

Ja, das ist möglich:

> Er wollte dich gestern gesehen haben.

Der epistemische Gebrauch von "wollen" ist mindestens möglich im Indikativ Präsens, Präteritum, und im Konjunktiv Präteritum und tritt nur zusammen mit einem Vollverb im Perfekt auf.

Dudenband 4 S.472.

Du kannst also sagen:

> Er hätte warten wollen. -> Er wollte gewartet haben wollen.
> Er hätte es machen müssen. -> Er wollte es gemacht haben müssen.
> Er hätte spielen dürfen. -> Er wollte gespielt haben dürfen.

Comment: Im letzten Absatz warf ich eine ähnliche Frage wie im Kommentar auf, ob in Hauptsätzen irgendein Gebrauch von "wollen" im Konjunktiv 2 gebräuchlich ist (z. B. Lässt sich ein volitives "wollen" in Konjunktiv 2 umsetzen?). Hier ist also ein epistemisches "wollen" des Konjunktivs fähig.

Comment: „Ich wollte, es wäre Nacht oder die Preußen kämen!“ ist ein Beispiel für den Konjunktiv II im Hauptsatz.

Answer (score 1):

The Konjunktiv II Perfekt is built with the *haben/sein* auxiliaries as the other Perfekt tenses are. And as *wollen* is a modal, the infinitive is used instead of the Partizip II.

> Er hätte warten wollen, aber …

Or do you mean plain Konjunktiv II? That's

> Er wollte warten, aber …

Those forms cannot be distinguished from Präteritum and thus they are seldom used. Instead the *würde* replacement is used. That's

> Er würde warten wollen, aber …

In general, the Konjunktiv II of *wollen* in not very common. That is because it is about counterfactual wishes. Wishes aren't facts, so marking them as counterfacts on top of that means the person is unsure about what they want.

Comment: Was für ein peinlicher Fehler von mir. Anstatt "Konjunktiv perfekt" wollte ich "Konjunktiv präteritum" sagen. Haben Sie noch längere Beispielsätze?

Comment: "**Ich wollt** ich wär ein Huhn / Es gäb nicht viel zu tun / Ich legte täglich nur ein Ei / und manchmal sogar zwei", am besten in der Version der Comedian Harmonists.

Comment: Ein typischer Beispielsatz mit so einem unklaren Wunsch wäre z.B. *Es sieht so aus, als würde er warten wollen.* oder *Es sieht so aus, als wollte er warten.* Wenn man über andere Leute spricht, ist ja oft nicht klar, was diese wirklich wollen. Allerdings ist der Indikativ ebenso gebräuchlich, besonders in der alternativen Formulierung mit *als ob*: *Es sieht so aus, als ob er warten will.*

Comment: Wenn ich mich recht entsinne, kann "wollen" neben eine Absicht auch eine Behauptung ausdrücken. Ist ein konjunktivischer Gebrauch von dieser Bedeutung ebenfalls möglich oder sogar gebräuchlicher?

Comment: *Er tut so, als wollte er warten.* Meinst du so etwas? Das hat aber weniger mit dem Verb *wollen* zu tun. *Er tut so, als würde er warten.* funktioniert genauso gut, mit einer leicht abweichenden Bedeutung. In beiden Fällen wird etwas als nicht-Fakt markiert.

Comment: Laut DWDS bedeutet der Satz "er will dich gestern gesehen haben" etwas wie "er behauptet, dich gestern gesehen zu haben". "wollen" in diesem Satz unterscheidet sich von dem in Ihren Sätzen, oder? Ich interessiere mich eigentlich mehr fürs Auftreten von "wollen" in Hauptsätzen und würde gern erfahren, ob man solche Sätze mit Konjunktiv 2 umschreiben kann.

Comment: In indirekter Rede ist der Konj II von "wollen" aber sehr häufig gebraucht, nicht? Ich kann dem letzten Absatz nicht ganz folgen.

Comment: Achso. Ja, dieses *Er will dich gestern gesehen haben.* ist eine Behauptungs-Variante der reinen Annahme  *Er wird dich gestern gesehen haben.* (auch Futur II genannt). Es gibt z.B. auch noch *Er muss dich gestern gesehen haben.*, was ebenfalls eine Behauptung darstellt. Man kann das alles auch in den Konjunktiv II setzen, was der Behauptung oder Annahme eine große Unsicherheit bescheinigt. Sollen, dürfen und können werden ähnlich subjektiv eingesetzt.